# Sample for Edit Url for a FB Page Tab App

Tags: facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

I am implementing the edit url FB Page Tab App. But it needs the initialization which should happen when the app is added to a fanpage by the admin.

I am looking for the initial callback/notification to my app-url when the app is loaded on the fanpage. (I have looked at this already - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

I am looking for a sample that shows the handling of the signed_request in this case, from the fan-page-load and what details are available/etc..

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of handling the signed request:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

in $data there will be a "page" object that has a "admin" boolean.  This will tell you if the current user of the page tab application is an admin of the page that the app is a tab of.

Comment: Thanks DMCS ! This is what I am looking for.. Just one thing I want to confirm.. After the first call by the admin to the app, the app needs to be initialized. Subsequently the admin is expected to change parameters using the 'edit', right ?

Comment: Actually, from your information, I don't know what's on your app website, so it's hard to say what the admin will do.  It's up to you the developer of the app to show/hide certain functionality of your pages displayed by your website app.

Comment: Is this sample also valid for the post on the 'edit Url' (one that is called when the admin does a 'Go to App' on the edit-page ? I have tried to do this on the post and I am not getting the signed_request, although I get the signed_request as above when the app url is triggered thru clicks on the tab on the page.

Comment: Confirmed that the EDIT URL from 'Go to app' does not send in a signed_request or access_token. It also seems that the edit-url workflow does not support the security support that Facebook provides to 'Page Tab Url' for Tab Apps. This question remains unanswered, unfortunately.

Comment: The signed_request should be sent to your page tab app in the iframe when facebook initially loads it, if not you should file it as a bug with Facebook at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: before I file a bug, would like to confirm if anybody else is getting a POST call with the signed_request when Edit URL for the page tab app is invoked. This seems a relatively new feature and is it possible that Facebook does not yet have the POST/signed_request implemented for 'Edit URLs' ? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the edit url part was not part of the original question.  I feel I have done more than enough work to warrant an acceptance of my answer for a code example of how to decode the signed_request .  You should post your edit url issue as a new question, rather than dragging one question out into many many questions.  What would Ghandi do?

Comment: The first sentence - 'I am implementing the edit url FB Page Tab App' talks about the edit url specifically. But I agree/thank you for all your help (sincerely). I will post this as a separate question, no use dragging this - if it is confusing..